# Angularjs ng-repeat more data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

js app

Now In html I user ng-repeat

```
<div class="row">
 <div ng-repeat="item in Photos" class="col col-33"style="border:none">
    <img ng-src="{{item.image}}" imageonload style="width:100px;height:120px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block">
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I have 5 images in list but only 3 of them is on dipslay. Another 2 is not shown on display. How can I solve problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your json please

Comment: Include your json. It may help.

Answer (score 0):

May be your images have same url value in the `Photos` array so you need to use `ng-repeat` with `track by $index` like this

```
<div class="row">
 <div ng-repeat="item in Photos track by $index" class="col col-33"style="border:none">
    <img ng-src="{{item.image}}" imageonload style="width:100px;height:120px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok then can you console log $scope.Photos from your controller  and check if there are 5 data

Answer (score 0):

Try `col-xs-2` instead of `col-33`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="item in Photos" class="col col-xs-2">
    <img ng-src="{{item.image}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this give 5 but all of them are near. I want it to go another line after every 3 image

Comment: Ok so the issue is not to get five images, but to get the three in one line and the next two in other row. This cannot be achieved in single repeat, you need to divide it into two arrays and use two ng-repeat's using javascript.

Comment: $scope.imagearray = {
       'images' : []
  };
 var i,j,temparray,chunk = 3;
 for (i=0,j=$scope. Photos.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
   temparray = $scope. Photos.slice(i,i+chunk);
        $scope.imagearray.images.push(temparray);
  }
  
    <div  ng-repeat="img in imagearray.images">
        <span class="singleReward" ng-repeat="item in img" ></span>
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.imagearray = {
       'images' : []
  };
 var i,j,temparray,chunk = 3;
 for (i=0,j=$scope. Photos.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
   temparray = $scope. Photos.slice(i,i+chunk);
        $scope.imagearray.images.push(temparray);
  }

    <div  ng-repeat="img in imagearray.images">
        <span ng-repeat="item in img" ></span>
        </div>
```